# Unexpected row(0) Entity Framework, store insert , update and delete

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

i have seen this issue in different articles but i am facing same problem can any one tel me what exactly i am doing wrong will be appreciated if some one guide me my code that how can i am achieving to delete records. using store procedure in entity framework.

[image]

**Store Procedure:-**

```
USE [Gap]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOrganization]
    @ORGID bigint
AS
BEGIN

    delete from Organizations where ORG_ID=@ORGID
    delete from Institutes where INS_FK_ORGID=@ORGID
    delete from Branches where BRN_FK_ORGID=@ORGID

END
```

**Cs Code:-**

```
public static bool DeleteOrganization(long oRGID)
        {
            using (GapEntities1 Db = new GapEntities1())
            {
                try
                {

                    Db.DeleteOrganization(oRGID);

                    return true;

                }
                catch (EntitySqlException ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i am tring to delete it's deleting record from databse but page getting error after deleting

**Error:-**

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) EntityFramework
```

Comment: You need to call `Db.SaveChanges();` after `Db.DeleteOrganization(oRGID);` I believe.

Comment: Can you post your DB schema? If Institutes.INS_FK_ORGID if a FK on Organizations then the delete operation on Organizations is going to fail (assuming you have ref. integrity check on). In general you need to delete the child table records first, then the parent table. Personally I hate delete and usually implement an Enabled or Status bit flag rather than deleting.

Comment: Why are you deleting from other tables ... you should instead created the table with (delete cascade) option so instead once you delete the record from Organizations, It will automatically delete any records in Institutes and Branches ..

But for your current problem .. I think that there is no records in Institutes or Branches has the FK of the ORGID you are trying to delete.

Comment: records exist instite and branch regarding this

Comment: attaching screen shot of shema then tell me what i can do

Comment: @robnick i pasted image for schema now you cans see